# c++ lightweight https server to embed into app

Tags: c++

I need to embed a lightweight c++ webserver with https support. Is my best option boost.asio with their http server example as a starting point?

Any pointers welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used [pion](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library) with good results before. It is built on top of ASIO, probably a bit simpler, behaves almost the same way as asio. It basically lets you make register callback that gets called when a client accesses a certain url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't find anything about SSL/HTTPS in pion. Unless you can provide any links proving me wrong, pion is pretty much useless :(

Comment: http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_t_c_p_server.html

shows some funcs with ssl in the name. I think it is supposed to work with ssl.

Comment: thanks for the infos! however we already wrote our own https web server and apns push server using boost.asio within one day :) asio is just great.

Answer (score 1):

[Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) is also an alternative to boost::asio/pion.

See the [net library](http://pocoproject.org/docs/00100-GuidedTour.html#4).

Comment: Poco looks nice. However I'm already running boost.asio in my application and I probably don't want to mix poco and boost.. especially at the threading/synchronisation level. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I agree, there's no need to mix poco and boost. If you're already using boost, stick with it.

Comment: @godexsoft I've also looked for a lightweight C++ HTTPS server library, and there don't seem to be many out there. I've used [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) (no https) and boost::asio in the past. Boost::asio isn't bad, and your server code will be small. The only issue for me was that boost puts _everything_ in headers, and the compiler I'm forced to use is slow, which made for exceptionally slow compiles :(